# Mojolicious Routing and CamelCase

Tags: perl, routes, mojolicious, camelcasing

I have a my mojolicious routes set up like this:

```
my $r = $self->routes;
my $users = $r->route('/users')->to(controller => 'controller-users');

$users->get('/select')->to(                 action => 'select' );
$users->get('/list')->to(                   action => 'list' );
```

Where my user controller is defined in Users.pm, called Project::Controller::Users. This all works fine and without any problems. However, I also have some controllers like UserGroups. These are defined in the same way, Project::Controller::UserGroups.

However, the line

```
my $users = $r->route('/users')->to(controller => 'controller-usergroups');
```

doesn't work for that. It keeps trying to find the controller Project::Controller::Usergroups, which doesn't exist. What's the correct syntax for camelcase for the "to"-method of Mojolicious' router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
my $users = $r->route('/users')->to(controller => 'controller-userGroups');
```

EDIT:

Can you try it like this:

```
my $users = $r->route('/users')->to(namespace=> 'Project::Controller::UserGroups', action => 'users');
```

Based on this: http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Route_to_class

Comment: I did, and it still is looking for Project::Controller::Usergroups unfortunately

Comment: can you try this: namespace=> 'Project::Controller::UserGroups'

Comment: Yup, my $user_groups = $route->route('/user_groups')->to(namespace=> 'Project::Controller::UserGroups'); works. Thank you very much :)